# Is there a counterpart for zero forcing in communications in DSP?

Tags: digital-communications, dsp-core

If yes, what is forced to zero?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_forcing_equalizer

Answer (score 1):

If you understand zero forcing from the perspective of vector spaces, you would be able to identify it different systems including DSP. In essence you are projecting your equivalent (received vector in communications) in the null space of a specific subspace which makes signals lying in that subspace to be zeroed. In communications, this would be the null space of interfering users (in a multi user scenario).

What's more, you can extend this idea from vector space to Hilbert spaces. For ex: consider the vector/Hilbert space of N degree polynomial, now you might want to project your polynomial on the null space  of the subspace spanned by some polynomials which are not of your interest.

For ex: you might want to approximate a N degree polynomial by a M degree polynomial, $M<N$, then you can find the null space of the polynomials from degree $M+1$ uptil N (using gram Schmidt procedure if possible) and then project the N degree polynomial along that to zero force those terms. So you see the idea is generic. This last example of polynomial approximation I quoted is also an example of zero forcing in DSP, less trivial one though.

Mbaz has quoted a reference for a more trivial explanation.